# MySQL connection from different host

Tags: server, mysql

I have an Ubuntu server 18.04 with MySQL installed, I created 'user'@'localhost' and a 'user'@'%' account to connect from another computers in the network, ufw is disabled/masked on the server, I can connect to it from localhost, I even changed the Password hashing from Native to Unix Socket, but cannot from other computers in the network, any ideas what can be causing that?

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL doesn't listen on a network interface by default.  You have to configure it to.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

Changed the binding address to 0.0.0.0 instead of only 127.0.0.1